# Flash/html not working on all browsers on Mac

Tags: html, macos, cross-browser, internet-explorer-6, flash-cs5

I have been experiencing problems in using Flash on all browser on Mac.The same websites on Firefox,chrome,explorer work ok on Windows.the problem is just browsers on Mac and IE6.

flash is here ; http://www.evateknoloji.info/Temp/CS4.html

Has been anybody else been experiencing the same problem? Is there a solution?

Comment: !ProgramRelated ?? Move.To(" http://superuser.com ")

Answer (score 2):

I'm on a Mac and using Firefox, I don't see a problem with it.

Comment: thanks, I tried  on a mac in my office and it does not work yet, how can it be? can you try another browsers maybe chrome or safari ?

Comment: @Arzu Bulut Özçiçekçiler: Possible flash is not installed in your office or it is some old version (same story for IE6)? Same was the case in my previous job. They had a lone mac, for testing their websites and more often than not, it was not up to date / lacked some software...